# ¿ Por qué no me sale una escena en Unity correctamente asignada?

Tags: unity3d

Tengo en `Build settings` las escenas todas puestas. La **primera** es splash screen y la segunda es **titulo** que es la que me interesa y la **tercera** es el menú de juego, me salta directamente de splash que dura 5 segundos a la tercera, por qué ?

Pero lo he pensado también y es que no he dicho tampoco que esté `cierto tiempo` en la segunda pantalla por lo que creo que la ejecuta una milesima y carga la **tercera**. ¿ Con qué instrucción puedo hacer que se mantenga 4 segundos como el splash y que pase a la 3a escena ?

Answer (score 1):

¿Con splash screen te refieres al que trae por defecto unity o a uno que has creado tu?, y si es uno que has creado tu, ¿como haces el cambio de escenas?

Mi recomendación es que tengas un objeto en las escenas que tengan un script con el siguiente codigo:

```
public class MiScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public float duration;
    public string nextScene;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if(duration<0)
            Application.LoadLevel(nextScene);
        else
            duration -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Y desde el editor seteas la duracion y el nombre de la siguiente escena.

No lo he probado pero es para que pilles la idea.

Comment: Al final fue error mio disculpa, todo iba bien .